# PDFMiner - pdf2txt.py parsing text out of order

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdfminer

I'm new to both python and pdfminer, although not to programming in general.  I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7, and also in cygwin.

I'm writing a script with beautifulsoup to extract specific info from pdfs. To do that, I used pdf2txt to create both a .txt and a .html file of this pdf to use in testing.
Just the usual commands:

> python pdf2txt.py -o output.txt input.pdf
>
> python pdf2txt.py -o output.html input.pdf

They both have the same problem: Some lines of text appear out of order.
Run pdf2txt on this pdf and you'll see what I mean:
(edit: I found the original site.) It's the American Samoa one on this page: https://www.iamovers.org/ResourcesPublications/ShipperGuides.aspx?navItemNumber=580

For example, this is the correct layout of one section of page one of the pdf:

> Documents Required
>
> Copy of Passport (some ports require Passports for all family members
> listed on the 3299)
> Form CF-3299
> Supplemental Declaration (required by most ports)
> Detailed inventory in English
> Copy of Visa (if non-US citizen / permanent resident) / copy of Permanent
> Resident Card
> I-94 Stamp / Card
> Copy of Bill of Lading (OBL) / Air Waybill (AWB)
> Form DS-1504 (Diplomats)
> A-1 Visa (Diplomats)
> Importers Security Filing (ISF)

And this is how it comes out with both the txt and the html conversion using pdf2txt.py:

> Documents Required
>
> Copy of Passport (some ports require Passports for all family members listed on the 3299)
> Form CF-3299
> Supplemental Declaration (required by most ports)
> Detailed inventory in English
> Copy of Visa (if non-US citizen / permanent resident) / copy of Permanent Resident Card
>
> Copy of Bill of Lading (OBL) / Air Waybill (AWB)
> Form DS-1504 (Diplomats)
> A-1 Visa (Diplomats)
>
> Importers Security Filing (ISF)
>
> I-94 Stamp / Card

For some reason the lines beginning with the letter "I" are always taken from their place, and placed either on the next blank line, or a previous blank line. There are some other characters it keeps happening to as well.

I've posted this issue here: https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/issues/121

It has to be an issue with pdfminer. I don't yet know python well enough to go making changes in packages. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give my email address to some file hosting site so I can't look at the example you provided.

But, generally speaking, even if a PDF file only contains text in neatly ordered rows, PDF is still not a text file format. It's more like a script that tells the PDF reader which graphics and text elements to place where on the page and in what order.

You seem to want your plaintext output to match the layout of your PDF file but if you think about it that's not such a trivial requirement. You could assume (as pdf2txt apparently does) that the elements are already sorted within the PDF file, top-to-bottom, left-to-right, and then scan through the list of elements for each page, adding any extractable string or character you come across to the end of a string. But that's a naive assumption because there's no requirement for the elements in a PDF page to be ordered in any way (except back-to-front in case anything overlaps.)

Personally I've used the C# version of PDFTron's PDFNet a lot. It's able to produce a list of all words on a text page with each word represented by a string and a bounding box. You can then create rules for chaining words together into lines and for ordering those lines, although it does get more complicated the more types of layout you want to take into account (e.g. text arranged in two columns, table layouts, vertical text along the borders of the page, etc.)

There's a [Python version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PDFTron-PDFNet-SDK-for-Python/5.7), too, so maybe you could have a look at that. But the bottom line is that what you're trying to do is actually not that simple.

Comment: It's asking for your email? Argh. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: I've been reading a lot of posts about pdf scraping here, so I know it's not trivial. But the fact that it always happens with lines that begin with "I", "J", and a few other characters makes me think that it's a solvable problem.

And PDFNet looks pretty sweet, but I'm limited to free solutions atm.

Comment: I had a look at PDFMiner and it does seem to do some layout recognition, so it may be PDFMiner that's acting up after all. Have you tried playing with the -F and -A switches?